# Creating a mosaic with montage wrapper

Tags: python, glob, astropy, mosaic, montage

I'm having trouble using montage wrapper to create a mosaic in Python. I am trying to create a 3 x 3 mosaic of M33 and have all 59 photos in a folder 'M33' as shown in my code. There are about 4 photos for each tile and also darks and lights in the folder. The photos are fitz files and the only other thing in my 'M33' folder is my iPython notebook. Here is what I tried:

```
import montage_wrapper as montage
montage.mosaic('~/Documents/Modern Observational Techniques/M33', 'mosaic', background_match=True)
```

I can't find any good examples online of people using montage wrapper and the documentation isn't very helpful for me.

Comment: You don't state what your actual problem is. Do things crash? Is the image garbled? Do you get a Python exception?

Comment: Depending on the underlying code, you probably want to replace the tilde to your actual home directory. Or use `os.path.join` and `os.path.expanduser`. Just providing the `~` by itself like this, will likely be interpreted as a literal tilde.